# How can I create an alias to point to an uploaded file?

Tags: 8, files, path-aliases

Users uploading a file within content create a name like
my_site.com/sites/default/files/import/CrazyLongNamefile.pdf
They would like to alias it for referencing in other media (print) like
my_site.com/GoodName.pdf

URL alias works fine for other things, but not files (that I can determine)

The File (Field) module looks like it would probably do what I want, but it hasn't been touched for Drupal 8 in a while.

Is there a way (module, custom code) to provide an alternative path to a file that I can make available to content creators?

Comment: Do you absolutely have to have these aliases in the root? If not an easy solution be to rewrite everything from (e.g.) /assets/(.+) to /sites/default/files/$1

Comment: This is what the client wants, yes. They want to be able to advertise in print an easy to get to URL

Comment: URL shortener comes to my mind. There are a couple of Drupal modules implementing known URL shorteners. You could probably also use Drupal to build your own URL shortener. And does the redirects module not also accept any URL?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Clive and base oh his comment, to redirect all files to another route you can use `.htaccess` route direction. So,

**first solution:**
add to following line in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteRule ^sites/default/files/(.*)$ /files/$1 [L,NC]
```

**note:** you can use whatever you want instead of `files`, like `assets` etc.

**PS:** if your files are Media types, with `pathauto` module you can create a pattern to redirect them additionally you can let the user override them the what path he wants.

**second solution:**
install https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity module and then with `pathauto` module you can create an alias for files.  like `files/file-title`.

**third-solution**: use https://www.drupal.org/project/path_file module

> The Path File module allows content editors to upload files and
> specify the url at which they will be available. Normally, when
> uploading a file to Drupal with the same name as an existing file, it
> is given a new name instead of overwriting the existing file. This can
> problematic when file urls are referenced in content, menus, etc but
> may need to be updated in the future. The Path File module allows you
> to mitigate the impact of those changes by setting up a canonical url
> alias which will always point to the most up-to-date file